# Python: I want to check if row has multiple same values for any of the columns in a dataframe and if yes, replace the repeated value with null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*I am new to stackoverflow, please excuse my formatting*

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

A       B       null    A       D
A       B       C       F       C
```

Since in the first row, Col4 has a repeated value i.e. A, I want to replace it with null.
Similarly, in the second row, Col5 has a repeated value, I want to replace it with null.

The final dataframe should look like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

A       B       null    null    D
A       B       C       F       null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1` for processes by rows:

```
df = df.apply(pd.Series.drop_duplicates, axis=1)
print (df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
0    A    B  NaN  NaN    D
1    A    B    C    F  NaN
```

Comment: It's a great code for small dataframes. However, "apply" function is very slow for dataframes with ~1 million records. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: @RishabGupta - hmmm, not so easy, can you check `df1 = df.reset_index().melt('index').drop_duplicates(['index','value']).assign(g= lambda x: x.groupby('variable').cumcount())` and then `df2 = df1.pivot('g','variable','value')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.series.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','C'], 'b':['B','D'], 'c':['A', 'D']})
mask = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1)

print(df.mask(mask, 'None'))
```

Output:

```
   a  b     c                                                                                                                         
0  A  B  None                                                                                                                         
1  C  D  None
```